# POST Json request not working. NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have started learning Python few days ago. I want to create a simple API, but POST request it isn't working because of a error code.

Python Code:

```
 @app.route('/addPerson', methods=['POST'])
def add_person():
    try:
        _json = request.json
        _name = _json['Name']
        _lastname = _json['Lastname']
        _parentName = _json['ParentName']
        _birthdate = _json['Birthdate']
        _gender = _json['Gender']
        _driversLicense = _json['DriversLicense']
        _personalNo = _json['PersonalNo']
        _phoneNo = _json['PhoneNoRks']
        if _name and _lastname and _personalNo and request.method == 'POST':
            sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Person(Name, Lastname, ParentName, Birthdate, Gender, DriversLicense, PersonalNo, PhoneNoRks)" \
                       " VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            bindData = (_name, _lastname, _parentName, _birthdate, _gender, _driversLicense, _personalNo, _phoneNo)
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sqlQuery, bindData)
            conn.commit()
            response = jsonify('Person added successfully!')
            response.status_code = 200
            return response
        else:
            return not_found()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

Error that it's appearing:

```
File "C:\Users\dreni\PycharmProjects\Projekti1\main.py", line 76, in add_person
cursor.close()
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs through until:

> ```
> try:
>      if _name and _lastname and _personalNo and request.method == 'POST':
>          # does things and create a variable named 
>          cursor = ....
>          # does more things I omitted for brevity
> except Exception as e:
>     print(e)
> finally:
>     cursor.close()    # ERROR here
>     conn.close()
> ```

the `finally:` part is **always** executed:

- even when the coditional `if _name and _lastname and _personalNo and request.method == 'POST':` is not met (and hence `cursor` never created)
- even if you get an exception *before* `cursor` is created

In both cases the variable `cursor` is not created - hence the `NameError` inside the finally statement.

Fix: Only execute

> ```
>     cursor.close()
> ```

when `cursor` was created. You could f.e. at the start do `cursor = None` and do

```
if cursor:
    cursor.close()
```

here. If cursor is never set, it is `None`, hence falsy hence this will be skipped.